# Problem with executing "ssh-add" or eval 'ssh-agent' using Chef

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, chef-infra

I am trying to add private keys to an Amazon Linux box using Chef. The key is in s3, and I copy it over to the directory. Then I start the ssh-agent using "eval `ssh-agent`". Everything is good until the "ssh-add" section = it errors with "*Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.*". So it seems that eval ssh-agent didn't start.

```
execute "sudo aws s3 cp --region us-east-1 s3://xxxx/keyname ~/.ssh/keyname"
execute "eval `ssh-agent`" 
execute "ssh-add ~/.ssh/keyname" <--this is where it fails
```

I've verified that the key is there. I've also tried to do the steps manually by connecting to the box and running the commands - and it works.

But when it's in CHEF it fails.

Here is the error log if it helps:

```
================================================================================
Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[ssh-add ~/.ssh/keyname]'
================================================================================

Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '2'
---- Begin output of ssh-add ~/.ssh/keyname ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
---- End output of ssh-add ~/.ssh/keyname ----
Ran ssh-add ~/.ssh/keyname returned 2
```

I've hit a wall and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

leverage well knows cookbook for that, such as [users cookbook](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/users), which is a management of OS users and groups from databags. It also manages the distribution of ssh keys to a user's home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps in case anyone is interested:

So we add the key and change the perm to 600:

```
execute "sudo aws s3 cp --region us-east-1 s3://priv /root/.ssh/priv"
execute "sudo chmod 0600 /root/.ssh/priv"
```

We also copy .ssh/config

```
execute "sudo aws s3 cp --region us-east-1 s3://config
execute "sudo chmod 0644 /root/.ssh/config"
```

Now when its time to use.

```
ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add /root/.ssh/priv; git clone etc....
```